# How can I remove space between tableview header and first cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

How can I remove the space in the `UITableView` header an the content of the table?

I have tried the following but I still have space after the tableview header

```
tableView.contentOffset = CGPointZero
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, -20, 0)
```

Comment: did you find any solution??

Answer (score -2):

you can use this code for header remove and make less space between first cell,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    return 0.005f;// set this according to that you want...
 }
```

and you can also set footer as follows..

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 3.5f;// also set this one as you want ...
}
```

Comment: Instead of using 0.005f, you can also use FLT_EPSILON, which is the smallest positive float value.